# Discord.js Delete message through an existing function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, message

**The Issue**
When executing my code i am really getting no errors at the moment but would like to add to a function but have tried almost every way of handling it. At this point the variable has been removed due to confusion and frustration.

What needs to happen is, the User that initiates the command, their message gets deleted after a short delay. I have tried message.delete(1000) and other Variants for v12 but no luck. Not able to pass the "message" variable from my active function?

Maybe i am completely off and just making it hard on myself, i don't know. Honestly embarrassing that i couldn't figure out a message.delete. Please help. Apologies for the ignorance.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = "";
const PREFIX = "!";

const fs = require('fs');
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("The bot is active and ready to go!");
});

      bot.on('message', function(message) {
        if(message.content[0] === PREFIX) {
            let command = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ") + 1, message.content.length);

        }
    });

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {

        case "crash":
            bot.commands.get('crash').execute(message, args);
        break;

        case "hello":
            bot.commands.get('hello').execute(message, args);
        break;

        case "purge":
            bot.commands.get('purge').execute(message, args);
        break;
    }

});

bot.login(token);
```

Here is an example of "crash.js" for reference. Don't know if i need to execute delete from there?

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'crash',
    description: "Crash",
    execute(message, args){
        message.author.send("Here is the link you requested");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute delete from within your module. The message is passed as a full object so you just call the delete method on it. However, the [Options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) are an Object which means it needs to be defined as such. For clarity, I'm going to use another variable but this can be done inline.

```
let options = {
    timeout: 1000,
    reason: 'Because I said so.'
}

message.delete(options);
```

or inline...

```
message.delete({timeout: 1000});
```

Comment: Unexpected identifier "Reason".

Comment: Wasn't placing it in the correct place. I am obviously misunderstanding the execution structure of JS as a whole. As i said sorry for the ignorance. Thank you for the help, got it working.

Comment: Before i get too far into expanding this bot, how would i go about implementing .toLowerCase into this scenario? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @BrianChambers You may have been placing it in a location that expected synchronicity.  Node.js is inherently asynchronous, this can be confusing to those not accustomed to it.  For example, message.author.send is async so it's possible anything put after it could happen first if you didn't await it.  This is a long detailed subject so I suggest doing some research into it.  Keywords are asynchronous programming, callbacks, promises, and async/await.

Comment: @BrianChambers Where would you like it?  If you are talking about the command, I would put it in the switch statement ``switch(args[0].toLowerCase())``

Really, I wouldn't use a switch at all.  commands.get will be undefined if it's not there so your args[0] could be used directly.
```let command = bot.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()); if (command) { command.execute(message, args); } ```

Comment: Yea there is a ton too it but just this simple interaction has me so excited to figure out more. I am making this for a friend and would love nothing more than it to be more than usable for him. Thanks so much! Now to figure out the embeds.

Comment: The problem i am having with most of it is i am not understanding implimentation into a module. So say i want to have a purge command. I cannot simply add snippets into my code without it breaking completely. But when i add something to a module i have to error fix for hours because it's not carrying definitions. For example, when i try to embed through a module like i use to message,  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   Is what it is returning

Comment: The module is just an object, you have properties to describe it (name, description), and methods or functions to invoke (execute).  If you've programmed in any OOP language, it's no different really.

RichEmbed doesn't exist in v12, it's MessageEmbed now.